# Websockets em servidor windows

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Tudo bem galera, 
Já dei uma boa lida em vários tutorias da web referente ao `WebSockets`, achei muito legal e quis fazer uns testes de chat por questão de aprendizado.
O problema é que em todos os tutoriais que vi(até nas perguntas aqui no sop) só se fala em usar `Node.js` no lado do servidor, ou executar algum arquivo(php, a linguagem que uso) via linha de comando, coisa que não tenho acesso pois utilizo uma revenda windows da uol.

Por acaso há alguma maneira de se utilizar essa tecnologia no meu servidor sem os requesitos acima(algo como `javascript` e `php` sem essa de executar via linha de comando)? Já pesquisei bastante mas até agora nenhuma luz, coisa que me deixou bem desanimado pois parece ser algo que vale apena usar no dia a dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

supondo que você esteja utilizando socket.io, a comunicação de forma síncrona entre servidor e navegador **requer Node.js**

De forma resumida, quando você usa PHP, o navegador solicita o conteúdo do servidor e nunca o contrário; enquanto o Node.js pode por meio de evento do servidor comunicar com o navegador a qualquer momento, inclusive, por eventos de outros visitantes (ao realizar um broadcast, por exemplo, sempre que uma nova pessoa entrar na sala).

Ok? Você pode até utilizar o PHP para armazenar itens no banco, processar dados, entretanto, o lance em tempo real mesmo é JS do cliente >< Node.js

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Entendi, mas que pena não vou poder usar por causa do servidor que utilizo. Vou ter que usar o `longpolling` mesmo o `websocket` parecer mais recomendado.